# Keep mutable borrow alive outside of block

Tags: rust

How to resolve a borrowing issue when attempting to mutably borrow a vector within a loop? The error specifically mentions "cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time," and I've already tried enclosing the problematic code in blocks.

Is it because of the loop iterations? Why is Rust getting confused?

```rs
use std::option::Option;
use std::vec::Vec;

pub struct Node<Record> {
    pub character: char,
    pub children: Vec<Node<Record>>,
    pub record: Option<Record>
}

pub struct StringKeyedRecordSearcher<Record> {
    root_node: Node<Record>
}

impl<Record> StringKeyedRecordSearcher<Record> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            root_node: Node {
                character: 'f',
                children: Vec::new(),
                record: None
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn find_mutably(&mut self, path: &[char], create_missing_segments: bool) -> Option<&mut Node<Record>> {
        let mut selector: &mut Node<Record> = &mut self.root_node;

        for path_segment_index in 0..path.len() {
            let path_segment = path[path_segment_index];
            let potential_selector = {
                let mut_selector = &mut selector.children;
                mut_selector.iter_mut().find(|child| child.character == path_segment)
            };

            if let Some(mut new_selector) = potential_selector {
                selector = new_selector;
            } else if create_missing_segments {
                selector.children.push(Node {
                    character: path_segment,
                    children: Vec::new(),
                    record: None
                });
                
                selector = &mut selector.children[0];
            } else {
                return None;
            }
        }

        Some(selector)
    }

    pub fn set_record(&mut self, label: &str, record: Record) {
        // let path = label.chars().collect();
        let path = &['a', 'b', 'c'];
        let reference_to_target = self.find_mutably(path, true);

        reference_to_target.unwrap().record = Some(record);
    }
}
```

```rs
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `selector.children` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\string_keyed_record_searcher.rs:38:17
   |
25 |       pub fn find_mutably(&mut self, path: &[char], create_missing_segments: bool) -> Option<&mut Node<Record>> {
   |                           - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
31 |                   let mut_selector = &mut selector.children;
   |                                      ---------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
38 | /                 selector.children.push(Node {
39 | |                     character: path_segment,
40 | |                     children: Vec::new(),
41 | |                     record: None
42 | |                 });
   | |__________________^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
50 |           Some(selector)
   |           -------------- returning this value requires that `selector.children` is borrowed for `'1`
```

Tried surrounding the errored code with blocks